# How to create custom BaseController to keep data about user while user is logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I use `SimpleMembership` in my app and when I need to get the current user's  `userId` I use `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` but this invokes the database and I need to reduce this call to the database.

That is why I want to create `BaseController : Controller` to store `userId` here. What is the best way to implement this?

I can create:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
     public int CurrentUserId { get; set; }
     ...
```

And after login set this value. But I am sure that this should not be so simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the User property on your HttpContext to your logged in user.  Like this (pulled from my CustomPrincipal implementation)...

In your Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /// Code to get user
    ...
    ContextHelper.GetHttpContextBase().User = user;
}
```

In another helper class:

```
public static class ContextHelper
{
    public static HttpContextBase GetHttpContextBase()
    {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

Then in your BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public new HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; private set; }

    protected virtual new ICustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as ICustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ICustomPrincipal ` is what? `ContextHelper.GetHttpContextBase().user = user;` User can be my class for user right?

Comment: As stated, ICustomPrincipal is my implementation.  If your user is of a different type, you'll clearly need to change that.  The point is that you should set your currently logged in user to the User property of HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

I would use claims to store the user ID. This will persist the information in the cookie and eliminates the need to hit the database every time you need to access it.  Here is an [article on how to use federated authentication to persist custom claim information in the cookie](http://www.codetails.com/2013/05/25/using-claims-identity-with-simplemembership-in-asp-net-mvc/). This article specifically puts the user ID in the claims.  [SimpleMembership is already storing the roles in claims](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/improving-performance-of.html).